# how to prove the pythagorean theorem with an octagon?

Tags: geometry

I hope you guys can help this curious math layman, so let's get straight to the point. My question is: How can we prove with algebra the Pythagorean theorem with this following irregular octagon

[image]

Sorry for any mistakes English isn't my native language.

Comment: Please sort the link to the image.

Comment: You can see how the sum of the area of the red squares equals that of the grey square (each red square is two yellow rectangles, the grey one is four yellow triangles), Hence the theorem follows.

Comment: Maybe, i miss something, but isn't this only for the case of equal long legs of the triangle ?

Comment: That octagon is NOT regular.

Comment: It looks fine for the $45-45-90$ triangle, but it's not easy to see if the same idea would generalize to arbitrary right triangles. The interior rectangle wouldn't be a square, and a lot of the symmetry would be lost. It might still work, but it's not obvious that it would.